# STM32F411 SPI Issues

Tags: stm32, spi

My goal is to make communication between NRF24L01+ and STM32f411 ( STM32F411-Disco board )
I did SPI communication before, but it was 1 master and 1 slave, so ChipSelect pin was always low.
But in order to communicate with NRF24, you have to toggle CS pin every time you send data to it.

Problem is, SPI not working properly. Seems like there is issue between SPI Clock starting and CS, They are not synchronized.
If I add a little delay right before CS go high it all works fine.
You can see it on screenshots from logic analyzer.

[Screenshot1.Communication seems ok, but there is delay before CS goes high](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wt4y.jpg)

[Screenshot2.More delay time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQLZb.jpg)

[Screenshot3.Without delay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGHL7.jpg)

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include "stm32f4xx.h"


    void SPI1_INIT(void)
    {
        RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_SPI1EN; // Enable SPI1 Clock
    
        SPI1->CR1 |= SPI_CR1_BR_Msk;
        SPI1->CR1 |= SPI_CR1_MSTR;          //Bit 2 MSTR: Master selection
        SPI1->CR1 |= SPI_CR1_SSM | SPI_CR1_SSI;         
        SPI1->CR1 |= SPI_CR1_SPE;           //Bit 6 SPE: SPI enable
    }
    
    void SPI1_GPIO_INIT(void) // PA4 - SPI1_NSS | PA5-SPI1_SCK | PA6-SPI1_MISO| PA7-SPI1_MOSI
    {
        RCC->AHB1ENR |= RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIOAEN; //Enable GPIOA Clock
    
        GPIOA->MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODER4_0;  //PA4 GPIO OUT mde
        GPIOA->MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODER5_1;  //Enable Alternate function mode for GPIOA PA5
        GPIOA->MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODER6_1;  //Enable Alternate function mode for GPIOA PA6
        GPIOA->MODER |= GPIO_MODER_MODER7_1;  //Enable Alternate function mode for GPIOA PA7
    
        GPIOA->AFR[0] |= 0x5UL<<GPIO_AFRL_AFSEL5_Pos;  //GPIO alternate function set 0101 AF5 SPI PA5
        GPIOA->AFR[0] |= 0x5UL<<GPIO_AFRL_AFSEL6_Pos;  //GPIO alternate function set 0101 AF5 SPI PA6
        GPIOA->AFR[0] |= 0x5UL<<GPIO_AFRL_AFSEL7_Pos;  //GPIO alternate function set 0101 AF5 SPI PA7
    }
    
    void spi_send(uint8_t data)
    {
        while(!(SPI1->SR & SPI_SR_TXE)); // Wait for TX buffer is emptly
        SPI1->DR = data;                  // Send data to TX buffer
    }
    
    uint8_t spi_receive(void)
    {
        while(!(SPI1->SR & SPI_SR_RXNE));
        return SPI1->DR;
    }
    
    
    int main(void)
    {
    
        SPI1_GPIO_INIT();
        SPI1_INIT();
    
        for(;;){
    
            GPIOA->BSRR = GPIO_BSRR_BR4;
    
            while(!(SPI1->SR & SPI_SR_TXE)); // Wait for TX buffer empty
            SPI1->DR = 0xFF;                  // Send data to TX buffer
    
            while(!(SPI1->SR & SPI_SR_TXE));
            while ((SPI1->SR & SPI_SR_BSY));
    
            //for(uint32_t i = 0; i<10; i++);
    
            GPIOA->BSRR = GPIO_BSRR_BS4;
        }
    }
```

UPD. I managed to make it work by changing SPI CLK speed.
It was 62.5 Khz and i raised t to 4Mhz and it works fine, I have no idea why it not works on low CLK speed

[image: 4Mhz CLK]

Comment: I don't know this peripheral but usually you have to set the CS to low before you send a command and set it back to high after. Here you toggle the CS at every byte. Are you sure it is the right thing to do ?

Comment: Also, unless the SPI of this particular STM32 is different, you have to write a register SPI_CR2 with the number of bytes to exchange with the peripheral.

Comment: Finally, why not letting the STM32 manage the SS automatically ? check bit SSOE

Comment: Yes I do change CS on every byte on purpose. When i do that NRF24 should send me 0x0E every time i send 0xFF to it. This is just for testing purposes. 

About numbers of byte to exchange, it is in CR1 not CR2, and by default DFF bit is 0 which is 8 bit data.

According to reference manual if I do it hardware NSS, i have to turn off SPI in order to get CS back high which is not what i want

Comment: OK the SPI interface seems different than the one on STM32H7 that I am used to